# The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

As a owner I have already verify my gmail in `sendgrid`, when I sent a message with owner mail account then It has been sent, but when I try to sent mail as a customer with different mail account then show me error like this: That means customer also need to verify their mail account with sendGrid ?

```
{
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements',
      field: 'from',
      help: null
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know why.

I have tried code following this way:

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.contactForm = (req, res) => {
  const { email, name, message } = req.body;

  const emailData = {
    to: process.env.EMAIL_TO,
    from: email,
    subject: `Contact form - ${process.env.APP_NAME}`,
    text: `Email received from contact from \n Sender name: ${name} \n Sender email: ${email} \n Sender message: ${message}`,
    html: `
            <h4>Email received from contact form:</h4>
            <p>Sender name: ${name}</p>
            <p>Sender email: ${email}</p>
            <p>Sender message: ${message}</p>
            <hr />
            <p>This email may contain sensetive information</p>
 
        `,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(emailData)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Message sent");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response.body);
    });
};
```

Any suggestion Please.

Answer (score 1):

Sendgrid (along with other bulk email vendors) requires you to send every email messages From: a well-known address.  You may not send mail via Sendgrid so it looks to the recipient like it came from an arbitrary unverified email account.

Why not? Spam.

Companies like Sendgrid go to a lot of trouble to prevent their customers from using  their services to send spam messages. If they let their customers send spam messages, their servers would be blocked by gmail, outlook, and the other big email providers, and would appear in the anti-spam blocklists used by smaller email providers.  If that happened it would quickly wreck their business.

So, any email account you claim as the From address in a Sendgrid message must be verified.

Comment: Interestingly I have two SendGrid accounts: my older one can send from any address (doesn't even have any verified sender) and my newer one gets the error unless using a verified sender. Did they change the rules at some point, and grandfathered existing accounts?

Comment: @remram same as well. Never ran into this issue before on my old sendgrid account. But I am experiencing it now on my new one. I don't have a dedicated IP Address on the new account yet, maybe that's the difference?

Comment: Update: got an email March 14 letting me know that "Unverified Senders won’t be able to send email if they aren’t verified by May 1, 2023." I don't know if that matches our situation, since I don't have a Sender at all, but they might be aligning the requirements for old accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you really can't send emails via **SendGrid** from unverified emails. To do this - you need to use another one email service, for example, i used **SendInBlue** to do this (upd: **SendInBlue** changed name and now they are **Brevo**)